# .htaccess rewrite folder-like url to existing html page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My local project's root is **localhost/website**

I created the file localhost/website/.htaccess with the following contents:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^content/(.*)$ content/$1.html [L]
```

What I exactly want to achieve:
**localhost/website/main** -> **localhost/website/content/main.html**
where **localhost/website/content/main.html** actually does exist.

I tried several rules but none of them worked for me. Somehow I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect `/main` to `/content/main` you'd have to omit the `content/` from the first argument.

Comment: tried it and it gives me an internal server error.

apache log:
"Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace."

I tried it also with a rewrite condition:
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^content/(.*)$ [NC]

Answer (score 1):

The following does the trick

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*content/[^/]*\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ content/$1\.html [L]
```

Comment: `RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*content/[^/]*\.html$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ content/$1\.html [L]`